# How to fix bad version in eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am getting this bad version error as shown below. How to fix this. Do I need to have a separate jar file for each version of java?

[image: Bad Version Error]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/images/Bad_version.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to fix this.

Is this a plugin that you created, or did you download it from somewhere?

I've never seen this myself, but I suspect that you are running Eclipse using an older version of Java (e.g. 1.5) and trying to use a plugin that was compiled for Java 1.6.  Assuming that is the case you can:

- upgrade the JDK used to run Eclipse to 1.6,
- try to find a version of the plugin that was compiled for the Java 1.5 platform, or
- download the plugin sources and build it for Java 1.5 yourself.

> Do I need to have a separate jar file for each version of java?

No.  A JAR file built for a Java 1.5 target platform should also work on a Java 1.6 platform.  (Just not the other way around ...)

Comment: It is my plugin. Yeah I built it in Java 1.6 and then tried to run it on 1.5, so it is not backward compatible.

Answer (score 2):

I got similar kind of error once and I was not able to fix it. And I ended up removing the plugin (EMF Plugin) and installing it on a new setup of Eclipse.

Now, I use [Yoxos On-demand](http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/yoxos-ondemand/) where you can create/add/remove Eclipse plugins with no effort. This is the best Eclipse customizer I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

You are running on an older version of Java than the code was compiled for.